# Forms authentication ticket is storing password in a cookie?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication

It's recommended that we should never store passwords in cookies. 
By using and storing .net forms authentication tickets in cookies aren't we doing just that?

Answer (score 1):

No, because:

1. Ticket does not contain password. It contains just information about user it was created for (user name), date when it was created, date when it expires.
2. Information above is encrypted and can only be decrypted by server.